# Photo not being displayed, yet it's in the page source

Tags: php

I am very frustrated with this one. I am trying to display photos on my webpage and they are not showing up. They are going into the database correctly. They are going into the server correctly (i can download them from the server). They show up in the page source correctly, but they don't show up! Here is what the page source looks like for the photos not showing up...

```
<div id="nextpicone">
<a href="fullsize.php?image=userphotos/dscf3119.jpg" ><img           src="http://www.mysite.com/userphotos/thumbs/dscf3119.jpg" name="mynextpicone"></img></a>

</div>

 <div id="nextpictwo">
<a href="fullsize.php?image=userphotos/dscf0988.jpg" ><img   src="http://www.mysite.com/userphotos/thumbs/dscf0988.jpg" name="mynextpictwo"></img></a>

</div>

<div id="nextpicthree">
<a href="fullsize.php?image=userphotos/dscf0063.jpg" ><img     src="http://www.mysite.com/userphotos/thumbs/dscf0063.jpg" name="mynextpicthree"></img></a>
</div>
```

The photos are being dynamically called with php and sql to grab them out of the database. To my knowledge, everything is working as it should. Only the first one is showing up actually. But why don't the others show up??? (disregard the stack overflow formatting, there aren't really spaces in the img tags like shown)

Comment: did u check opening images with the url dat being displayed in the page source????

Comment: Uhm... `<img></img>`? You mean `<img />`?

Comment: Aside from the sources not being actual images, your `<img>` tag needs to be self-closing: `<img src=... />`

Comment: This error message is generated when the web server is trying to access a file that does not exist or has been configured incorrectly

Comment: but i can download the pics from the server

Comment: the </img> to <img /> tag issue was not the problem...

Comment: @Nochbag You likely misunderstood. Your `img` tag needs to look like `<img     src="http://www.mysite.com/userphotos/thumbs/dscf0063.jpg" name="mynextpicthree" />` WITHOUT a tag after it that looks like `</img>` or `<img/>` .

Comment: no, that's what i tried. i was just unclear before i guess

Comment: this is wha'ts shown now:  <img src="http://www.mysite.com/userphotos/thumbs/dscf0988.jpg" name="mynextpictwo"/>

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, drove me nuts. My images were dynamically generated on the server using GD, and randomly some images were not granted read permissions on the Network Solutions shared hosting package.

I used the following function to verify permissions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php

and if read permissions did not exist I recreated the file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the cause of your problem, but shouldn't the img tag be closed after you have defined its attributes rather then closed by another tab ex:

```
<img  src="http://www.mysite.com/userphotos/thumbs/dscf3119.jpg" name="mynextpicone" />
```

I've never seen an image opening tag and closing tag, it usually is only one tag that is self closing, if that makes sense.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: unfortunately not, but if i open the image's url it displays:  Error 403 Forbidden This error message is generated when the web server is trying to access a file that does not exist or has been configured incorrectly